# Can't boot Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: boot

( first sorry for my english. ) Hi please help I can't find a solution I'm searching the web 11 hours and I can't find a solution. :(

I can't boot Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS alongside with windows.  But after restarting the pc and when I hit enter on grub 2 for Windows 7, I get a black screen for 2 seconds and then its return back to grub.  BUT when I select Windows 7 restore Vaio care it will boot, but I don't have an option top open Cmd to fix something.  Please help me out.  Here is my Bootinfo from Boot-repair

http://paste.ubuntu.com/975358/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grub does not show a Windows 8 option after dual boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/210914/grub-does-not-show-a-windows-8-option-after-dual-boot)

Answer (score 4):

From your booted Ubuntu system, use the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This should detect Windows 7 and add it or fix it.

If nothing happens, boot from the Windows 7 CD and go to recovery console:

```
bootrec / fixmbr
```

Then

```
bootrec / fixboot
```

As you are in the recovery mode, use Windows 7 fix boot errors tool. (Forgot the exact name of the tool) and reboot.

Now you would have Windows but not Ubuntu.

Try reinstalling Ubuntu - put MBR partition into sda (as opposed to sdb like before)
or try `sudo update-grub` from the live CD.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and the following solution worked for me:

1. Download and install "Boot-repair" while in Ubuntu.

   See the guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).
2. Once "Boot-repair" is installed go to your "Dash" and type "boot-repair" to open the application.
3. When in "boot-repair":

   - click on "advanced options", check the "Reinstall GRUB" box;
   - Then click on the "Other options" tab;
   - Check the "Repair Windows boot files"' box.

   Click "Apply" and let the process go on until your system restarts.
4. When you're at the GRUB boot screen, select the normal Windows startup option.

   The Windows Recovery is supposed to start now.
   Later on Recovery will ask you to restart.
5. When you see the GRUB screen, again choose that same Windows option. It should hopefully boot into Windows now.

Hope it works for you as well!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick, one-step solution for you.

---

Open Terminal in Ubuntu, and run the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot, and try choosing Windows from the boot menu again.

---

If that didn't work, try this instead. Open Terminal in Ubuntu, and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

After a few seconds, Boot Repair's main window will open. Click on *Recommended repair*.

Reboot, and try choosing Windows from the boot menu again.

---

If everything went well, you should be up and running by now.

---

#### Glossary

> **[Command, command line](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal/)**: the traditional Unix environment , where you type commands to tell the computer what to do.
>
> **[Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal/)**: an application that allows you to access the command line. Open it by hitting its keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>