# Ubuntu installed, cant boot

Tags: boot, hp, 13.04

```
ERROR: Boot disk not detected or HARDDRIVE has Failed.
```

I have a new HP ENVY23 touchsmart. The machine came with windows 8 preinstalled.

Windows 8 has been removed. The recovery partition exists but can only be seen under gparted, not in the file browser. The Ubuntu partitions seem fine.

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 but I cannot boot from the harddisk. I can boot from a usbkey and the live instance shows Ubuntu to be installed.

Is there some sort of protection preventing me from installing another OS?

UPDATE: I am able to Access and load the Ubuntu install

Steps: on startup hit ESC

UFEI Application > HDD with install > EFI > ubuntu > grub64.efi

This is not an ideal solution

Comment: i'm assuming your pc came with UEFI. did you install from the 32-bit or 64-bit Ubuntu cd?

Comment: yes it did have UFEI, I installed from the 64bit

Comment: yes these have all been disabled

Comment: is it possible to fix so I can boot strait into ubuntu?

Comment: It sounds like you installed ubuntu in efi mode, then disabled efi, and now the system can't boot in bios mode.  Don't do that.  Turn efi back on.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not a complete answer**
The newer flavours of Ubuntu with the signed keys for secure boot enabled and or capable machines should mean you can do an install (standalone or dualboot) with Secure Boot enabled. [**if question described how and when uefi and or secure boot were enable/disabled then could be more helpful] Am no expert or qualified in any way but [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/211077/102029) is an answer from somebody who is qualified and an expert that mentions a few points of interest to what could be more than applicable here; the author of which also wrote [this](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html) with regard Secure Boot.  Additionally the explanation of problems regarding switching back to BIOS (may be referred to as Legacy) is very well done in an easy to understand way can be found [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/bios.html).

Going by your update which confirms you are using an uefi entry to boot Ubuntu.
What has possibly happened is that switching from uefi to whichever setting switches off uefi just means you do not have the right boot files in the right place. Grub can not load for same reason (that is without using the method you describe in your update)

It may be that switching the firmware(BIOS) settings back to the same as they were when Ubuntu was installed will boot Ubuntu.