# How do I get Ubuntu 13.04 to recognize my pre-installed windows 8 OS?

Tags: installation, 13.04, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I am completely new to installing Ubuntu. I really wanted an easy install however it seems that is impossible. I am familiar with using ubuntu though and I would like to be able to have it on this computer.

I checked my partitions and I have 5. 4 of which are recovery partitions. I cannot find a video online of how to get it to work like this with my current setup.

I cannot stress enough that the explanation will have to be **painfully simple**.

I may not be able to run ubuntu on my pc if this is a complicated fix.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sidenote: Use the 64bit version of Ubuntu if you want to dual boot a preinstalled Windows 8. Probably you need to boot it in (U)EFI mode, not in BIOS or legacy mode.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you just have a single hard-drive on your machine.

You need to identify carefully(sometimes there are hidden partitons).

**Step 1:**

First information you need is to find if your partitions on the drive. And what are their contents.

**Step 2:**
Find if they are primary partions or Logical ones.(There can be only 4 partitions on a drive. Your 4 may be primary while a 5th be logical)

**Step 3:**
You will need to free at least one primary partition.(Chose carefully), By free i mean destroy one partition to get free space.

You may also remove all the other recovery drives but that is upto you.

This can be done from the manager in windows or using third party software (easily found by google search)

**Step 4:**
Burn a Ubuntu latest version .iso file to a DVD. You can find that [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

**Step 5.**
Insert the disk and boot from the CD and perform installation of OS.

#### Alternative option:

**Option 1:**

If you don't want to sacrifice the recovery drives. A wubi installation from the Ubuntu Disc is also a option which will install ubuntu inside your windows.

#### Header 3

[Wubi Download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer)

**Option 2:**

Use a virtual machine software like ([Virtual Box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Box))  to run the Ubuntu on windows(wubi is a better option though)

### IF you just want grub from Ubuntu to recognize your Windows part ion for a dual boot

follow this link:
[Grub does not show a Windows 8 option after dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210914/grub-does-not-show-a-windows-8-option-after-dual-boot)

Answer (score 0):

With UEFI and Windows 8, Microsoft has made it difficult (intentionally?). And if you have an Ultrabook it is more complicated as you have Intel SRT that uses RAID and dual video, each requires some settings and changes to work.

With Windows 8, you do not have the 4 primary partition limit that MBR(msdso) has because UEFI needs gpt partitioning which has a 128 partition limit.

If not an Ultrabook
Also shows Windows 8 screens

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

Shows install with screen shots.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI