# Need major help: Ubuntu 13.10 not detecting Windows 8 operating system

Tags: 13.04, kernel, software-installation

Just tried installing Ubuntu for a class, but during installation it could not detect my Windows 8 operating system. It has a few options on what to do but I don't want to ruin my new computer. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

1. Select "Something else
2. Create a new partition.
   Format: ext2, ext3 or ext4 (preferably ext4)
   Mount point: /
   Size: Whatever you want, should be more than 20GB
3. Make another partition.
   Format: swap
   Size: A bit more than the amount of ram you have eg. 16 GB ram, 20 GB swap
   4: One more partition.
   Type: Reserved BIOS boot
   Size: 2 MB
4. Click the ext partition.

You should be able to safely install. This is what I had to do. Just a note: GRUB may not detect Windows. A run of Boot Repair (google it) should solve it. I'll reply back when I test it.

Answer (score 0):

`Ubuntu` installer, by default, recognizes both `Windows 8` and `Windows 8.1`.

If `Windows` is not being recognized by Ubuntu Installer, this means that it probably won't auto-configure Windows 8 into [`GRUB`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB). You can try the following, but **there's still a chance that this might break your Windows bootloader and you'll have to reinstall it** (See last).

It's always wise to **back up** (Windows). Now that you've been warned,

1. Instead of default installation, use custom partitions. See [this](http://athurion.hubpages.com/hub/Installing-Ubuntu-1204-LTS-with-customize-partition).
2. Try booting up. If `GRUB` gets `Windows`, you're good. Otherwise, do *step 3*.
3. Follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210914/grub-does-not-show-a-windows-8-option-after-dual-boot) to manually configure `GRUB` to give you the option for dual boot.

If the above didn't work, you can reset to `Windows`-only, see [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/).

Hope this helps.