# Ubuntu on Gigabyte p27k

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus

I'm planning to upgrade to Ubuntu from Windows7

What should I expect with the following specifications?

---

4th Generation Intel® Core™ i7 4700MQ Processor 2.4GHz

8x3 GB memory DDR3 1.35v

Mobile Intel® HM87 Express Chipset

Intel® HD Graphics 4600

NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 765M GDDR5 2GB - optimus tech

128GB mSATA SSD + 1TB 2.5" 9.5mm HDD 5400rpm

---

I'm completely new to ubuntu and linux

Does Ubuntu automatically detect and install all the drivers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) aned also see [How do I install additional drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

It is more beneficial to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows for you now if you are willing to give Ubuntu a shot and in 95% of the cases no errors will pop up!

Be aware of the process as it *may* give some problems only in the first boot process, I suggest going through the following thread and print it or have an offline copy:

[Lost Windows 7 in GRUB after installing Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450185/lost-windows-7-in-grub-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04)

Mainly this is what you will need in case windows boot failed (mentioned in the previous link):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Some problems also *may* arise for your graphic cards management, at first it will detect the Intel chipset and work perfectly with it, if you found your self comfortable then no need for installing the nVidia chipset driver (depending on your work).

After being familiar with the environment you will see yourself depending on Ubuntu in every day-to-day tasks :)

Comment: If you're going to say that in 95% of the cases Ubuntu works out of the box then say that *first* instead of scaring people away with all the problems they *might* have!  ;)
*Excellent first answer on AskUbuntu!!!*
**Tip:** use "*" and "**" when you type to add emphasis instead of quotes! (try it next time)

Comment: @Fabby Don't worry. For me i had sufficient amount of headaches with Windows that i am quite sure in whatever situation i am transferring. But i guess unedited version might really scared away those "undetermined" people.

Comment: Nice edit, still new but happy to make some time to help the open source community the way they help me ;)