# Cannot see windows 7 in boot menu after installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I had windows xp and windows 7 in my system. I installed Ubuntu 14.10 into the XP partition and from then on the system directly boots into Ubuntu and doesnot even show windows 7 in the boot options but I can access the files of windows from Ubuntu. Kindly help me out here I'm a completely newbie to ubuntu and i know nothing.

Here is my bootfileinfo

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10102886/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lost Windows 7 in GRUB after installing Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/450185/lost-windows-7-in-grub-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`sudo update-grub2`

and have the OS prober attempt to place Win7 back in your `grub.cfg`

Reboot

Comment: after updating also it shows only ubuntu but not windows again :(

Comment: @BeeKay, sorry, I went looking and the best I came up with is [lost-windows-7-in-grub-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/450185/lost-windows-7-in-grub-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04). Good luck.