# Can't find windows 8 in the Grub menu [ubuntu 14.04]

Tags: 14.04, grub2, windows

So i wanted to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 8 as i need windows for certain programs for school.
I tried installing and it went smooth, but when i needed windows 8 i couldn't find the option for booting it on the Grub menu. So i searched for ''System32" in the files and i it's still there but i can't boot it. I have a system image for windows 8 on my external hard drive. is there a way to get windows 8 on the Grub menu, or do i have to format the the hard drive deleting Ubuntu and everything else?

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me few months back. You may want to install and run the Boot Repair and run a recommended repair.

If this did not work, Rob Smith's post will make your day.

[Grub does not show a Windows 8 option after dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210914/grub-does-not-show-a-windows-8-option-after-dual-boot)

best of luck