# Restore EFI System Partition to state before installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, uninstall

I found this thread that says how to delete GRUB2 [Uninstalling GRUB from UEFI laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304558/uninstalling-grub-from-uefi-laptop)

But I'm not sure if it applies to me or if I'm doing the things correctly, I'll attach a few screenshots about the contents of EFI Partition and I would appreciate if you guide me what to delete and what to rename, I want to remove GRUB2 and restore the Partition to the original state (It came with Windows 8.1 pre-installed).

According to the thread, deleting the Ubuntu and GRUB folders should be enough, but I feel it won't be enough since there are weird things like `/EFI/EFI/Ubuntu` (Why two folders with EFI?) `/EFI/Boot` and `EFI/EFI/Boot`, etc. you will see in the pictures but my instinc tells me, deleting won't be enough... :s

Here I uploaded the screenshots, please take a look at them:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCyzH.png

Thanks for your attention :)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't modified anything in `\EFI\Microsoft` (as it looks to me), then deleting the `ubuntu` folder next to the `Microsoft` folder should be sufficient.

(If you have modified the contents then you should overwrite the Microsoft directory with Windows' `bcdboot`, have a look at the related section for instructions.)

Regarding the confusion about the EFI folders:

```
mount | grep efi
none on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw)
```

As you can see in the example from my system the ESP is mounted to `/boot/efi/` and itself contains an `EFI` folder. This is how it should be by default and you don't need to delete anything outside of `/boot/efi/` as this doesn't belong to the ESP.

### Related:

- [How do I remove "Ubuntu" in the bios boot menu? (UEFI)](https://askubuntu.com/q/63610/40581)
- [Uninstalled Ubuntu 14.04, can't boot Windows 8 stuck GNU GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/a/536278/40581) - One of my answers that shows how to use `bcdboot`