# Cannot boot into Windows 8.1 after "Trying Ubuntu" from a USB stick

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

I'm a student who wants to get his feet wet in Linux so I thought I would try Ubuntu. I downloaded the 14.04.1 LTS from the Ubuntu site and created a USB stick with it. I also disabled fast boot in the Control Panel before attempting this.

My PC is a Lenovo y510p laptop that came preloaded with Windows 8.1. I also had both UEFI and SecureBoot enabled in the BIOS.

Also, I tried to run boot-repair to fix (from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) thread) without success. Here is my most recent attempt
http://paste2.org/a0AW7PDP

EDIT: After two days of trying different things to fix my boot I gave up and reinstalled Windows. Been meaning to do it anyways. Thank you ver much @LiveWireBT for your help on the issue. I certainly learned a lot from the experience!

Comment: Can you select and run Windows from the EFI boot menu (some function key at power-on, varies by machine, which offers device/OS boot choices.  Maybe select HDD if Windows is not offered.

Comment: Yes I can select Windows in the boot menu however I get an error message which causes a reboot and starts the troubleshooting boot screen

Comment: I cannot find a statement in the description that Ubuntu was installed, while the link lists linux partitions.

Answer (score 0):

The best and safest way to fix it is to [create a bootstick with Windows 8 installer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media), from which you can run Windows' boot fix.

Boot Repair sometimes does strange stuff, like replacing Windows' boot loader with GRUB2. As the GRUB EFI only loads the normal GRUB2, which is located on the stick, it won't work.

Comment: I tried using a USB boot disk created with the method above however I haven't seemed to have any success. Startup Repair in the advanced options isn't fixing it. Not sure how I would go about running Windows boot fix.

Comment: Is this what you were referring to?http://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader

Comment: @LyleFerguson `bcdboot C:\Windows /s S: /f UEFI` is the vital part. Different situation, same solution: http://askubuntu.com/q/536262/40581

Comment: @LiveWireBT That command seemed to work as I now have two copies of Windows Boot Manager in my boot order now.How ever I still can't boot into Windows, with either listing of the boot manager. Not sure how t post screenshots from a really crappy smartphone either.

Comment: @LyleFerguson You need to also mount the EFI System Partition (ESP) in Windows (S: in the example, but might be different for you). That should then overwrite the files on the ESP with proper ones from Windows. Probably rename `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTx64.efi` on the ESP to something else, so that this file also is created new.

Comment: @LiveWireBT Yes, I had to mount the ESP drive in diskpart. I'll try it again while renaming my old file and see what happens