# Windows 10 upgrade attempt destroyed both my Ubuntu and itself (windows 8.1). How do I wipe/format my hard drive to start fresh and try again?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-8

I had been dual-booting with Ubuntu and windows 8.1 for a while now without issue. However, when attempting my free upgrade to windows 10, it killed both. I am not entirely sure why, but it looks like it wiped a partition. I now do not have a useable computer. My boss provided me with a way to clean install windows 10 from a cd, but the process refuses to make a new partition for it, stating that I need GBT format and I am in MBR. 
Hence I am trying to determine how to format my hard drive to GBT now (I really dont even know what any of this means). My boss suggested running the Ubuntu installer to re-format without actually installing Ubuntu. This is where I get stuck. I have the installer successfully booted, but dont know how to carry out this actual task (it seems that it will do a full ubuntu install).

Ultimately this is what I am trying to accomplish:
-I want to start fresh on my system, get it back to factory settings. It came with windows 8.1 pre-installed. Since I dont have an OS, I cant just run a system restore it seems. What can I do?
-I want to be able to upgrade my windows 8.1 to windows 10 BEFORE installing Ubuntu (since it is believed that upgrading to windows 10 with Ubuntu already on the system is what causes the problem). 
-I would like to be able to use both windows 10 and Ubuntu on my machine, I use each for respective occupation purposes.

Please let me know if you have any ideas or experience with this issue. I am not *great* with advanced computer stuff. I have been running around in circles with this and its all trial and error for me. Fortunately my data is backed up so I am not worried about annihilating my hard drive in the restoration process.

A couple of other things to note:
-My neighbor has a windows 7 disk. I would not install it (would not work anyway) but if I were to boot from it, could I theoretically complete a system restore from there? Again, my machine came with windows 8.1, not 7. 
-Because 8.1 came pre-installed on my machine I dont have a license key. Its electronically embedded in my BIOS and the manufactorer doesnt know it. I have no boot disk for it.

Comment: Just like Ubuntu, how you boot installer UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. If a new UEFI hardware system, Windows need gpt partitioning for UEFI boot. Windows uses MBR(msdos) only for BIOS boot. But if system was originally Windows 8 from vendor then it was UEFI with gpt partitioning.  Windows 7 default install is BIOS, but can be converted to UEFI install if on flash drive & efi boot files moved to correct place.

Comment: Ok, do you know how to convert my UEFI back to gpt partitioning? Apparently thats why windows 10 wont install, its all MBR instead (by the way, I have really no idea what any of this means... I am just relaying notifications). Supposedly I could use the Ubuntu installer to do this as instructed by my boss, but there doesnt seem to be any obvious way of accomplishing this is practice.

Comment: Post current partitions, so we are not suggesting the wrong thing. If you still have Windows, you may not have to erase & reinstall. `sudo parted -l` There are tools to convert MBR to gpt, but without knowing exactly what you have, I will not post link.

Comment: I tried some things and did manage to get windows 10 successfully installed! However, I still need to get Ubuntu re-installed alongside it without them killing each other. Still, thanks for your help, this is good progress.

Comment: Did you install in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? Use Windows to shrink the NTFS partition and reboot immediately so it can run chkdsk. Make sure fast startup is off. If UEFI, ubuntu should install with secure boot on, but many prefer it off. Be sure to boot Ubuntu in same boot mode as you installed Windows. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Comment: I believe I installed it in Legacy... that is what it currently boots into now. Do I need to disable secureboot if booting in Legacy? 
I am trying to follow the instructions here:
http://technozed.com/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows-10/
to install Ubuntu. When going to shrink my partitions, I have found that I already have 400GB of unallocated space (I had about 900gb before windows install, created a partition of 500 for it, and now have 400 left). Do I still need to shrink my primary partition or can I proceed with the install using the unallocated space?

Comment: Oh by the way, I did find that my windows is not activated yet, but the license key given by your applet is not working. I will try to phone support them about this but let me know if you have any other ideas.

Comment: Sorry, applet was provided by another user.

Comment: New Windows 8 systems have license key inside the UEFI only for the OEM/vendors version of Windows. You can convert a Windows 7 installer to UEFI, but it will not use the key in UEFI, you have to purchase another legal copy of Windows. May be better to reinstall Windows 8.

Comment: Ok thank you. I think I should be able to reinstall windows 8, obtain key, then upgrade to 10, then install Ubuntu. Before I begin this process, would you clarify, do I boot up/install windows 8 via UEFI or legacy? I still dont really understand the difference between the two and a lot of this is over my head. I will need to keep the hard drive partitions in a format that will run both widows 10 and ubuntu. Thank you!

Comment: Windows 8 from Vendors is only installed in UEFI boot mode. A user can restall in BIOS mode if they have another legal copy of Windows. And if Windows is in UEFI mode you must install Ubuntu in UEFI mode. Or if Windows is BIOS mode, you must install Ubuntu in BIOS mode.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reinstall Windows 8.1 from scratch. Use a valid legit key (if possible, or the Windows 10 upgrade will fail most likely).
2. Upgrade to Windows 10 from the Windows 8.1 (Windows Update).
3. Apply all the patches to Windows 10.
4. Insert the Ubuntu disk into your machine, boot from it, and the Ubuntu disk partition some free space from the Windows 10. This is where your Ubuntu will then be installed.

I would suggest going through all the Windows "motions" first then adding the Ubuntu afterwards.

If you continue having problems with Ubuntu partitioning your hard drive, during the Windows 8.1 installation, use the Advanced option to create a separate partition you will **later** install Ubuntu on (this is call unallocated space).

Also, if it ask during the Ubuntu installation, replace the Windows Boot Loader with Ubuntu's one, and make Ubuntu your main OS.

Let me know if this works out for you.

Comment: The issue is that I dont actually have any way to install windows 8.1 anymore. The license key is embedded in my BIOS. The theory is that if I could get a copy of windows 8.1 on my machine, it would read the key from my system. I may try using the windows creation media download tool to obtain it, but now I am concerned that my harddrive is not in the proper format to install windows 8.1 (as it was not for windows 10).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what to do, even though this is technically not Ubuntu topic. Go to http://gparted.org/ and download their live iso. After that, boot into it and use Gparted like you normally would, then wipe the table clean. After that, go online and find a Windows 8.1 iso to burn onto a usb/cd so you can reinstall that, then upgrade to Windows 10, and after that install Ubuntu. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok I am not familiar with gparted or any of this process but its definitely worth a try. Thank you! I lost focus when posting this question because of all the options but originally this was an ubuntu topic because my task was to use the ubuntu installer to format my hard drive in GBT so windows 10 installer would work (once the formatting were complete, I would abandon the Ubuntu installer without completing its actual installation- but I cant figure out how to do this...)

Answer (score 0):

You can download and use "hirens boot dvd" to get the partions back the way you want, I assume you already have created backup media to restore windows 8.1, if not then you must be having a valid license key for 8.1 or most likely the upgrade will fail/ give warning that you were a victim of piracy and need to activate the licence in 3 days. I would suggest using the microsoft media creation tool to download a fresh copy from Microsoft Website and install the Windows 10. After that you can install Ubuntu. If you do not have the media backed up then you can contact microsoft/vendor for the media, alternatively look for unaltered media from any other source.

Comment: I dont have any backup media for windows 8.1 as it did not come with my computer (this whole problem would be solved if it did). Microsoft support just wants to sell me a new license key, when I already paid for and have one stored somewhere in my BIOS.  I believe that technically, even if I were to download a pirated copy of 8.1, it would be legal since I have a paid license and claim to it. This is all theoretical but I am going to try your hirens boot dvd software.

Comment: These days you do not get the media, the os comes preinstalled and you need to create the media from the rescue partition, Microsoft may be wanting to sell you the media, not the license as you already have one, Check for your license key under the battery panel if its a laptop. Which vendors system is this, you can download the iso for that specific vendor. A pirated copy will not help if you use their license, the moment you upgrade to windows 10 it will mark it as pirated and will ask you to validate within 3 days and usually these are altered and unreliable, hence look for "Untouched" iso.

Comment: I have successfully clean installed windows 10, a copy provided from my boss. I have no idea where he got it from, but it appears to be running quite smoothly. I never even needed reinstall 8.1, I just did clean from windows 10 disk. Now they did ask me for a license key, but I chose the option to "do this later". I am uncertain if windows will allow me to use it indefinitely but 24 hours later, i have not been prompted for a license key. My boss has a theory that upon receiving the first update for 10, my license key will be read from my BIOS and microsoft will register it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve your 8.1 license key install windows 8.1 from any copy that is "untouched" you can use any license key you have at your disposal, then go to "rweverything.com" download the 64/32 bit "read/write portable utility" and run it, click on "ACPI" button and then in the "ACPI Table" pop up click on the "MSDM tab", at the bottom you should see the Product key in the "Data" entry, write this down, now right-click Computer, and then click Properties. Scroll down to the bottom of the window that appears, and then, under Windows activation, click Change product key. If you're prompted for permission to continue the process, click Continue. Once this is done you can continue with your upgrade to windows 10 through windows update and finally install Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you! To catch you up, I successfull clean installed windows 10 from my boss' disk. Not sure of the source, but it seems to be working. Never needed to get 8.1 first and then upgrade. It asked for my key on install but I selected "do it later". I followed your steps and retrieved the 25-digit key using the applet. I found my computer's properties and see there is a different 20-digit key already in place. Should I bother changing it to the applet one at this point? Windows 10 seems to be running fine for the time being with its own generated key (where did it get this key from anyway?)

Comment: The key you see can be a OEM key that came with the copy of windows 10, if you can validate this then its ok no need to mess around further, the key you got from the read/write portable utility is one that is in your BIOS, so ideally yes you should use that key. If the other key is working don't bother, just let it be but note down the original key you get from the utility. Try and validate windows first if it gives problem then change the key with yours and try validating, if it still gives problem call Microsoft for a phone validation with your key.

Comment: I am discovering that the key generated by the applet does not activate windows 10. Could this be because the key in my bios is from windows 8.1 and since I never converted from there (8.1 does not exist on my system anymore, I clean installed to 10) the key did not convert to a windows 10 one? I will call microsoft about it but let me know if you have any thoughts.

Comment: This utility extracts the key from bios, make sure you enter it correctly, if the key is not activating, it may be that microsoft is complaining about it being used earlier, anyways you need to be ready to give them information about where you purchased, the model and vendor info, etc. I have installed and validated win 10 directly without issues, was asking you to download windows 10 from microsoft as the copy your boss gave may be vendor specific and an oem copy that can complain about other vendors key, btw, did you try validating your windows 10 before changing the key?

Comment: Any updates on your phone activation with Microsoft, please do not tell them how you extracted this from the bios. They may find some reason not to manually activate this key, just keep it simple that this is your product key.

Comment: Thank you. I have to shelve the activation for another day. I managed to get Ubuntu back up which was time sensitive because I use it for work. Theoretically windows 10 is on my computer and the partition for it was not deleted during installation of ubuntu. It does not appear as an option in GRUB, though a windows recovery mode does. I am clueless. Next step is to figure out how to access windows again (preferably I would be able to choose between ubuntu and windows in GRUB) and try having them activate the key. Any thoughts? I will try again soon.

Comment: Now that things are done the way they are done, nothing more can be done! Check out this article it may help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/210914/grub-does-not-show-a-windows-8-option-after-dual-boot

Comment: Oh no, am I permanently unable to access windows without wiping my hard drive again (I will if I have to, my data is backed up)? Why is everything so complicated, it seems like this should be an easy task; choose which OS you want to run. Ok I might give it another go tomorrow, but I am in the midst of planning for burning man as well!

Comment: It seems you are in for a long haul, follow one procedure and keep us updated, you had two issues, I presume the issue of you not being able to get your windows key is resolved, the second issue is to access windows 10, there are numerous posts and links that point to this solution, just make sure you follow one and if you run into other problems then ask for help. I hope you are able to achieve this. One advice is if you choose to wipe the drive and restart, use a copy downloaded from Microsoft not from an unreliable source, the reason for this I have already enumerated earlier.

Comment: Tomorrow I am leaving for burning man and then to Europe.I will continue to work with Linux as I travel but probably wont have time to really focus on restoring both OS's. I have not resolved the license key yet, will try right after burning man. Ya know I am starting to think it might just be easier to buy a new laptop (presumably they will have windows 10 pre-installed by the time I get back- months), which I can get at Target for $300; I have already spent 15+ hours working on this... Then I can work Linux on one, windows on the other and put these silly issues to bed! I will update you!