# I'm dual booting windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to upgrade windows 7 to version 10

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, upgrade, windows-7, windows-10

Has anyone done this yet? I think Microsoft finally got it right with windows and I'm ready to upgrade my windows OS to 10. The only issue is that I do not want to lose my Ubuntu partition. Is there anything that I need to know before upgrading?

Comment: Check this issue before making any changes http://askubuntu.com/questions/664310/windows-10-upgrade-attempt-destroyed-both-my-ubuntu-and-itself-windows-8-1-ho/664320

Comment: Is your Windows UEFI or BIOS? Either way make sure you have good backups of both systems. Some have Windows not fully update & have to restore. And many with BIOS and Ubuntu in a logical partition are finding it erases the Linux partition. Backup partition table. `sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > PTsda.txt` http://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue/655080#655080

Comment: It's BIOS I've had this laptop since 2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 will overwrite your GRUB, but you can simply recover it with a live CD. Boot from live CD and open a terminal after upgrading and run "sudo fdisk -l" and remember the device your system is installed on. Not the partitions but the whole disk. It is usually /dev/sda or /dev/sdb. Then run "grub-install ".

Comment: `boot-repair` will automate this.

Comment: Don't want to discourage anyone, but that's not the way to install GRUB from a LiveCD. Do check out [the wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_the_LiveCD_terminal).

Comment: I've managed to do this several times and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Windows 10 from Windows 7 will only replace the boot manager with the Windows one. If it asks you for the partitioning, be sure to select ONLY the Windows partition. If you want to use the Windows 10 Boot Manager, it's OK, but you have to add the boot entry for Ubuntu to it. (How-To: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/devtest/adding-boot-entries)
If you want to revert back to GRUB, follow this guide: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Take a look at both boot managers:

Windows 10 Boot Manager

[image: Windows 10 Boot Manager]

Ubuntu GRUB Boot Manager

[image: Ubuntu GRUB Boot Manager]

You could also install the BURG Boot manager. (How-To: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/install-and-configure-burg-in-ubuntu.html)

BURG Boot Manager

[image: BURG Boot Manager]

Comment: Burg is outdated though. It hasn't been updated in years

Comment: @answerSeeker Thanks for the info! I really didn't know that.