# Trouble Reinstalling Windows 8.1

Tags: reinstall

I installed Linux Ubuntu 15.04 on my laptop (hp stream 13) after it crashed.
however I realized that while Ubuntu is amazing its very limited in gaming and other things. I would like to know is there any way to reinstall windows 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your windows key you can download windows 10 and install windows 10 directly instead of Windows 8, check out this post to find your windows key if you do not have it written down. [Windows 10 upgrade attempt destroyed both my Ubuntu and itself (windows 8.1). How do I wipe/format my hard drive to start fresh and try again?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664310/windows-10-upgrade-attempt-destroyed-both-my-ubuntu-and-itself-windows-8-1-ho/664699?noredirect=1#comment963854_664699)
Consider using Ubuntu side by side with Windows (Dual Boot) and once you are comfortable you can move to Ubuntu for good.

Comment: Thanks for answering but how could I install windows 10 from ubuntu?

Comment: You could use virtualization, read more about it here, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualMachines I personally prefer VMWare but you can try any of them. But that is not what I meant windows and Ubuntu side by side, I meant dual boot the system. If you want more suggestions let me know which option you prefer. One more thing download windows 10 from microsoft through the microsoft tool not an unreliable source as I have already mentioned in the other post.