# Can't boot to windows 8 after Ubuntu 14.04.2 install

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

I tried boot-repair and followed the steps it asked me and showed everything as ok on completion of the program. I restarted the system and  it automatically booted Ubuntu without showing any option for windows. Here is my output before and after running the boot-repair program:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12306439/

P.S. I am a complete newbie in Linux and this is my first attempt at any OS except Windows so I am completely at loss here,

Comment: Login into ubuntu, open terminal and give sudo update-grub && sudo reboot now   . That should do it

Comment: @WeareBorg Well I tried it and I did not get any entry for Windows so I am not sure if I did it right. `sanjay@Kaos:~$ sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for sanjay: 
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-63-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-63-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done`

Answer (score 0):

From the file you uploaded at paste.ubuntu.com, I see that you must see GRUB that allow you to select between Ubuntu and windows.

If you can see grub2 during booting, you can select windows from there.

If you don't see GRUB , try pressing `Esc` key repeatedly just after you turn on your device. This may help you enter the GRUB.

Also try this

1. Boot into ubuntu. Open terminal by pressing `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`t`.
2. enter `sudo update-grub`. press `Enter` key.
3. reboot.

Comment: I can see grub2 alright. But the problem is no option for windows is present in the Grub menu. Also when I try to select UEFI from the menu by pressing `F9`. I dont get any positive result and I am back again on the Grub menu.

Comment: read http://askubuntu.com/questions/210914/grub-does-not-show-a-windows-8-option-after-dual-boot

Comment: Thanks @Kashish. I have read the suggested thread but I am stuck in installing rEFInd at the moment.  Ubuntu software Center says its installed but I can't seems to work out how do I start it??

Comment: As mentioned [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html),
an easier way to install rEFInd is to enter the following commands in the terminal.

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rodsmith/refind`                    and
`sudo apt-get update`                                                                      and
`sudo apt-get install refind`                                       

After installing rEFInd,you dont need to do anything else except rebooting, It will appear on boot.

Answer (score 0):

Several points:

- Your disk uses GPT, and there's evidence of an EFI-mode Windows boot loader. On a GPT disk Windows *must* boot in EFI mode. This in turn means that, if GRUB controls the boot process, it *must* be an EFI-mode version of GRUB; the BIOS-mode GRUB will be useless to you.
- You've got both BIOS-mode and EFI-mode GRUB installations. This makes it hard to tell which GRUB is in control of the boot process. Given the preceding point, if the BIOS-mode GRUB ends up being run, it's Game Over in terms of booting Windows, at least for that particular boot. The best way to ensure that this won't happen is to disable the Compatibility Support Module (CSM), aka legacy-mode boot support, in your firmware setup utility. (Many Ubuntu installation guides provide the bad advice to enable this feature. Doing so creates confusion and problems like yours.)
- Your [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) is near the end of the disk rather than near the beginning, where it's more commonly found. Your configuration *is* legal, but the fact that it's unusual could explain the next point....
- Your `grub.cfg` file shows no evidence of a Windows entry, which is consistent with what you're reporting. Creating a fresh GRUB configuration file might fix this problem. Typing `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu will create a new configuration file; however, whatever problem caused Windows to not be detected before might persist and prevent it from being detected again. Thus, this procedure might be ineffective. Running [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) is a more radical possible solution; this re-installs *all* of GRUB. Again, it's not guaranteed to do any better, and there's a small chance that it will actually make matters worse.
- Another approach is to bypass GRUB. There's evidence that you tried my [rEFInd,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) but you don't say whether it worked or why you abandoned it. In any event, rEFInd is usually better at detecting and launching Windows than is GRUB, so it's worth trying (again). You can try rEFInd on a CD-R or USB flash drive as a test if you don't want to (re-)install it on your hard disk, then install it to your disk only if you're satisfied that rEFInd is working.

So in sum, I recommend you try your choice of rEFInd, `update-grub`, or Boot Repair, in increasing order of riskiness. (rEFInd is least risky if you try it from a USB flash drive or CD-R, and slightly more risky if you install it to your hard disk.) I also strongly recommend you disable your CSM, no matter what other solution you attempt.

Comment: Thank you @RodSmith I downloaded the rEFInd utility, installed with Ubuntu Software Center but I am  not able to see it anywhere when I restart my system!! So I tried to follow [your guide](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#linux) but I am stuck trying to find the correct procedure to it. Do I copy the .deb into the /boot/efi/EFi or first I unpack it into a folder and then copy its contents recursively? [This](http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/?source=typ_redirect) is the rEFInd I am using.