# No selection in Bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, easybcd

I'm new to ubuntu. Yesterday I installed ubuntu 16.04LTS (as dual boot with windows 8.1) and now I'm having a problem with bootloader. When I switched on my laptop there'll no selection option for OS. Laptop just turn on in Windows 8.1. If I need to switch to Ubuntu I have to restart and press 'F9' then the Ubuntu selection comes. This is how I can switch to Ubuntu.

How to get selection window for both Ubuntu and Windows, when laptop turns on.
I saw that EasyBCD for windows can do the trick. And one of my friends told me that grub can do the trick on ubuntu. What is the best and easiest ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you're a little confused. EasyBCD is a tool for working with the bootsector and such, while GRUB is a bootloader.

Comment: Thanks. Then what is the tool which can fix the problem I'm having ? EasyBCD or GRUB ?

Comment: take a gander at https://askubuntu.com/questions/210914/grub-does-not-show-a-windows-8-option-after-dual-boot/270242#270242