# grub menu not showing windows 7 option on dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, ubuntu-mate

It is showing just two options,
 one is **Ubuntu** and second is **Advance Options**.

First, it was not even showing me the grub menu, I was booting directly into the Ubuntu. After reading some answers, I installed `update-grub`. And reinstalled it. Now grub menu is showing successfully but still, I can't see windows 7 option in grub menu.

**I want to use both Windows and Linux, how can I use my system in dual mode or how can I bring windows 7 option in grub boot menu?**

I have installed `boot-repair` and did everything as it directs me. Nothing happened.

I have read many of the answers everyone suggesting either `update-grub` or `boot-repair`. I've did both

Output of `fdisk -l`

[image]

Comment: This is not a full answer, however I have had success in the past using a tool called grub customizer to add windows installations back to the grub menu. It can be found [on this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer).

Comment: I have downloaded and opened it, but how can I mention windows 7 OS in it?

Comment: It looks like one of those NTFS partitions is your windows 7 installation, so you would add an "Other" operating system and enter a Boot Sequence like the one inside [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/637035), replacing the drive with something like `(hd0,msdos3)`.

Comment: Have you reviewed [Windows 8 doesn't dual boot doesn't show on grub menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210914/grub-does-not-show-a-windows-8-option-after-dual-boot)? It seems to have the most trusted answers. Also most duplicate questions are closed to this link.

Comment: Your fdisk says you do not have a working Windows. Windows only boots from a primary NTFS partition with the boot flag. You have no primary NTFS partitions and have boot flag on a Linux partition. Was sda1  a small NTFS  boot partition for a Windows install in a logical partition?

Comment: @oldfred - I believe that only applies to the windows boot loader. Grub can launch windows from anywhere. Though you may be right about it having to be a primary partition

Comment: I update the grub customizer and make an entry of
 **WIndows 7** 
Type : **Chainloader**
Partition: **/dev/sda5 (NTFS)**
Boot sequence: **set root='(hd0,5)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 09F28D92406A6EEA
drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
chainloader +1**

And on clicking on **Windows 7** option from boot menu, I'm getting an error: **BOOTMGR is missing, Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart**

Comment: I am not sure grub boots Windows in a logical partition, but the Windows boot partition typically has bootmgr & BCD. Those files can be in c: drive and Windows in a primary partition with boot flag can be repaired to add them. But Windows repair disk will not see a logical partition to repair it. Typically you keep Windows in primary partitions, and have Linux in logical partitions as Linux works without issue from logical partitions.

Comment: What should I do at this time?