# How to use windows 8 bootloader instead of ubuntu 13.04grub?

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-8

I have dual booted my netbook with windows 8 pro and ubuntu 13.04.

i do not like grub and think the windows 8 bootloader is a lot more clean and sharp.

Is there a way to use the windows bootloader instead of the horrible sticky looking grub?

Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use (in Windows) **[EasyBCD](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml)** - a Windows tool that allows you to create a multi boot environment in order to run multiple operating systems on the same computer.

After you fix Windows boot loader, when you will go in Ubuntu, Grub will appear anyway. To prevent this, you must to edit `/etc/default/grub` file (`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`) and make `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`:

[image: edit grub]

Run `sudo update-grub` afterwards to update `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: Is there a better program than easybcd as it is not free.

Comment: @apad121 Go to http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml and you will see: **Licence / Price: Freeware / $0**. That does makes you think the idea that the program is free?

Comment: i tried it but it would not boot into ubuntu.

Comment: @apad121 Maybe you didn't tried correctly. I am sure that works. You have all EasyBCD documentation here: http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/EasyBCD+Documentation+Home

Comment: I did it but I messed it up and now my PC would not boot. It is stuck on the boot. What should I do.

Comment: @apad121 You should give a maximum attention when you play with thing like these... Ok, when you open PC, where you are stuck, what does appear on the window?

Comment: It gets stuck on the windows bootloader. it says error isert disc and restart.

Comment: @apad121 Boot from the Ubuntu live CD or USB and follow the instructions from here: [How can I repair grub?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: Would this fix windows bootloader too?

Comment: @apad121 Yes, of course, you can fix after from Ubuntu. Use this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/144038/147044

Comment: I fixed the boot in another way, I did not is your way as I fixed my machine before I noticed your post. I made a windows 8 recovery USB on my windows 7 desktop pc. I went into the CD and chose repair but it said that it is not repairable. I chose refresh as well it says that it doesn't know which partition to access. I fixed it by typing into the cmd