# Uninstall Ubuntu 15.04 from dual boot on windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uninstall, 15.04

I want to uninstall ubuntu 15.04 . I dual booted it with windows 8.1. Please help me step by step, how to safely uninstall it...

I dont want to loose any data. I used 2gb as swap area and 13 gb for ubuntu home partition .  and will it remove grub also?
And yes, I don't have windows 8.1 recovery disk/installation disk.
What is 'System Reserved' Drive??? Will it also delete after deleting ubuntu partition?

Comment: I agree with Karel, likely to be a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you @karel 
and  What is 'System Reserved' Drive??? Will it also delete after deleting ubuntu partition?

Comment: According to [Windows 7: System Reserved Partition](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/256532-system-reserved-partition.html) the System Reserved partition is either: 1.  the manufacturer's (HP, Acer, etc.) recovery tools and/or the Windows Repair Files or 2. The System Reserved partition is required in order for the PC to boot using the default Windows bootloader, so you shouldn't delete it.

Answer (score 0):

All the steps should be covered here at

[How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Hope this helps and Good Luck

Ask for more help If necessary

UPDATE: To the asker who was interested in EasyBCD, I have asked the question about it a while ago [How to use windows 8 bootloader instead of ubuntu 13.04grub?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297531/how-to-use-windows-8-bootloader-instead-of-ubuntu-13-04grub)

Comment: What is 'System Reserved' Drive??? Will it also delete after deleting ubuntu partition?

Comment: Its shouldn't be deleted if you follow the steps as shown in the link.

Comment: 'System Reserved Drive' is the drive where your Windows folders are kept which are extremely important for Windows

Comment: but it was not there before dual boot... And is easyBCD is safe to use?
 there is (in your given link) no tutorials  for windows 8.1 and  ubuntu 15.04. So,i'm little bit worried

Comment: Don't worry, I have used EasyBCD before, It did look pretty and it worked

Comment: However, be careful NOT TO DELETE MORE THAN YOU NEED TO IN EASYBCD MENUS, Plus don't try to fix EasyBCD when it is working.

Comment: I will be happy to help you with that

Comment: I tried WIndows 8 and Ubuntu 13.10 with it a while back

Comment: Okay, and write to MBR and and the next step is enough to fix the boot?
then i have to delete the partition .. and then i can directly boot into windows,, GRUB menu will not show then , right?

Actually i'm so immature so asking ques a lot , dont mind

Comment: Well, supposedly or you can use a recovery drive which you can find online.

Comment: I will recommend making a recovery USB from Windows and you can go into start-up repair and it will restore the original boot loader for you http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-8/create-usb-recovery-drive. You could try to write to MBR. However, Easy BCD is the tool for Dual booting rather than for just one system.

Comment: Plz Like if this answer helps